# C#: Add TabControl tab by name

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I have form with TabControl. I can add Tab by doing:

`TabControl.TabPages.Add(TabPage)`

`TabPage` is name of one of tab pages I have.

I would like to do

`TabControl.TabPages.Add("TabPage")`

Where `TabPage` is String object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: And why are you unable to do that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btz4twwd.aspx

Comment: Because it adds empty tab, not one I have with controls in it.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon? You don't. The `TabControl` is a collection of `TabPage` objects. You can give a `TabPage` a name that you can use to refer to it, though.

So if you want to select or remove a tabpage, you could do something like this (please excuse the nasty code modified from my app, I had to notepad-refactor it to simplify it):

```
private void ConfigureTabs()
{
    var config = GetConfig();

    foreach (TabPage tabPage in tabControl.TabPages)
    {
        if (config.IsTabVisible(tabPage.Name) == false)
        {
            tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
        }
    }

    if (tabControl.TabPages.ContainsKey(config.DefaultTabName))
    {
        tabControl.SelectTab(config.DefaultTabName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to clarify - I have TabControl with let's say three TabPage objects, that I have named tabPage1, tabPage2, tabPage3. If want to add one of those to my tabcontrol I can do that by using TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage1). How can I add this tabPage1 object, if I have it's name (witch is "tabPage1") in String variable called, let's say, name?

Answer (score 1):

Steps

1- Select the whole Tab control
2- On the Property window (Located on right side ) --> Tab Pages --> Click on (...) .
3- Once 1 & 2 done you will see all Tabs...then You can change the name on Text..

I hope that helps.. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties of TabControl..then go to TabPages..Click the (collection)..Now you can edit the name of tab in TEXT field.

Answer (score 0):

If the tab you want to add is not in any control hierarchy then it is not possible. However if the tab is located somewhere else in the form you could write an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that finds the TabPage you specify and adds it to the TabCollection of the TabControl. Something like this:

```
public void AddEx(this TabCollection tabs, string name)
{
  var myTabPage = MyFindTabPageMethod(name);
  tabs.Add(myTabPage);    
}
```

So if the TabPage is located within some other TabCollection and you want to "move" it somewhere else then the above should work.

Now you can do:

```
TabControl.TabPages.AddEx("TabPage");
```